# Using serde attributes, can I convert before de/serialization and then use existing serde implementation?

Tags: rust, serde

I have an enum (imported from an external crate) that is called `ExtEnum`.

In my project I implemented a `serde` module called `extenum_fromstr` for it and I use it to de/serialize `ExtEnum` like so:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SomeStruct {
        #[serde(with = "extenum_fromstr")]
        ext_enum: ExtEnum,
        ...
}
```

This works fine.

Now, I have a different enum, let's call it `MyEnum` that can be converted to `ExtEnum` because it implements `impl TryFrom<ExtEnum> for MyEnum` and `impl TryFrom<MyEnum> for ExtEnum`.

I want to implement `serde` for `MyEnum` to behave just like the `serde` implementation for `ExtEnum` by taking advantage of the fact that I can convert `MyEnum` to `ExtEnum`.

Could I achieve this using only `serde` attributes? Something like:

```
#[serde(from = "ExtEnum", into = "ExtEnum", with = "extenum_fromstr")]
enum MyEnum {
        ...
}
```

This does not compile because `with` is not a valid container attribute. But is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, once again, we have:

```rust
mod ext { pub enum Enum; }

mod extenum_fromstr {
  pub fn deserialize(/* .. */) { .. }
}

impl TryFrom<ext::Enum> for My { .. }

#[serde(..)] // how to reuse TryFrom & deserialize?
enum My { .. }
```

Suggested strategy:

1. Implement `Deserialize` for an intermediate `Helper` type:

   [`#[serde(with = "extenum_fromstr")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#with)
2. Define `TryFrom<Helper> for My`

   (reusing `TryFrom<ext::Enum>`)
3. Define `My` as one that can be deserialized through `Helper`

   [`#[serde(try_from = "Helper")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from)

You can find the code with explanation on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use+serde%3B+%2F%2F+1.0.171%0A%0Ause+std%3A%3Aconvert%3A%3AInfallible%3B%0Ause+serde%3A%3ADeserialize%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F+We+have+an+external+crate+with+Enum+defined+there.%0Amod+ext+%7B%0A++pub+enum+Enum+%7B+%2F*+..+*%2F+%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F+And+accidentally+we%27ve+got+a+serde+module.%0Amod+extenum_fromstr+%7B%0A++pub+fn+deserialize%3C%27de%2C+D%3A+serde%3A%3ADeserializer%3C%27de%3E%3E%28_d%3A+D%29+-%3E+Result%3Csuper%3A%3Aext%3A%3AEnum%2C+D%3A%3AError%3E+%7B+todo%21%28%29+%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F+So+we%27ve+decided+to+exploit+them+for+our+own+type+My.%0A%0A%2F%2F+We%27ve+written+a+conversion+utility.%0Aimpl+TryFrom%3Cext%3A%3AEnum%3E+for+My+%7B%0A++type+Error+%3D+Infallible%3B%0A++fn+try_from%28_val%3A+ext%3A%3AEnum%29+-%3E+Result%3CMy%2C+Self%3A%3AError%3E+%7B+todo%21%28%29+%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F+Now+we+ask+ourselves%2C+what+shenanigans+is+required+in+order+to+implement+Deserialize%0A%0A%2F%2F+1%3A+a+top-level+newtype+wrapper%0A%23%5Bderive%28Deserialize%29%5D%0Astruct+Helper%28%23%5Bserde%28with+%3D+%22extenum_fromstr%22%29%5D+ext%3A%3AEnum%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F+2%3A+a+Helper-%3EMy+conversion+utility%2C+given+us+for+free%0Aimpl+TryFrom%3CHelper%3E+for+My+%7B%0A++type+Error+%3D+%3CMy+as+TryFrom%3Cext%3A%3AEnum%3E%3E%3A%3AError%3B%0A++fn+try_from%28val%3A+Helper%29+-%3E+Result%3CSelf%2C+Self%3A%3AError%3E+%7B+val.0.try_into%28%29+%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive%28Deserialize%29%5D%0A%23%5Bserde%28try_from+%3D+%22Helper%22%29%5D+%2F%2F+3%3A+a+serde+container-attribute%0Aenum+My+%7B+%2F*+..+*%2F+%7D%0A).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [`serde_with`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/3.2.0/serde_with/index.html) crate, which provides utilities for intermediate transformation of types. For your case [`TryFromInto`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/struct.TryFromInto.html) serves well. This adapter serializes a type `O` by converting it into a second type `T` and serializing `T`. Deserializing works analogue, by deserializing a `T` and then converting into `O`.

```rust
struct S {
    #[serde_as(as = "TryFromInto<T>")]
    value: O,
}
```

For serialization `O` needs to be `O: TryInto<T> + Clone`. For deserialization the opposite `T: TryInto<O>` is required. In both cases the `TryInto::Error` type must implement `Display`.

```rust
impl TryFrom<ExtEnum> for MyEnum { .. }
impl TryInto<ExtEnum> for MyEnum { .. }

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SomeStruct {
    #[serde_as(as = "TryFromInto<MyEnum>")]
    ext_enum: ExtEnum,
}
```

If you need a pure serde solution, check out the chapter [Deriving De/Serialize for type in a different crate](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html).

Comment: nit: You shouldn't implement `TryInto<ExtEnum> for MyEnum` implement `TryFrom<MyEnum> for ExtEnum` instead, it gives the former for free.

Comment: Does this even answer OPs question? They want to derive/implement `(De-)serialize` for `MyEnum` I don't see how this does it.

Comment: `ExtEnum` is from an external crate. That's why OP implemented deserialize_with utility for `ExtEnum`, and then wants to reuse it for the local `MyEnum`. I suggest the opposite approach: do ser/de for MyEnum, then reuse it for ExtEnum.

Comment: That sentence belongs into the answer somewhere.